# MVC on unobtrusive validation fire method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to run a method on my MVC view when the unobtrusive validation returns an error. My current script doesn't fire at all. I'm trying to only run a certain method when an error is returned.

I've tried on `$("#submitButton").click` and similar methods but to no avail.

Is there anyway to do this from the inline script only? does the validation have any triggers?

```
<fieldset class="step">
                <legend>
                    Contact:
                </legend>
                <p>Let us know how we can contact you with your quote, or anything else we may need from you coming up to your ski trip. </p>
                <div style=" float: left;">
                    <table>
                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                Full Name*
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, Model.Titles, "...........", new { style = "width:70px; padding: 5px;" })

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { style = "width:115px; padding: 5px;" })

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { style = "width:115px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                City*
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City, new { style = "width:320px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                Postcode*
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode, new { style = "width:320px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                Email*
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { style = "width:320px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                Telephone*
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Telephone, new { style = "width:320px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="height: 50px; padding: 5px;">
                            <td style="width: 187px;">
                                Preferred Time of Contact
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PreferredTime, new { style = "width:200px; padding: 5px;" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <input id="submitButton" type="image" alt="Submit" src="/images/global/submit_button.gif" />
            </fieldset>
```

edit: just tried binding to the invalid-form.validate method and it didnt work:

```
 $(function () {
    $("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
        alert('invalid!');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by an error is returned?  What do you see and what happens?

Comment: as in if the validation fails, then i'd like to be able to run a method

Comment: You can invoke the checking from jquery like this:

     var controls = $("#divid").find('.class');
     $.each(controls, function (index, item) {
       $("#form1").validate().element($(this));
       if ($(this).valid) {
           //skip it maybe
        }
        else {
         //do something, even an ajax call if need be
         }

Comment: clicking the submit button already fires the validate. I need to add extra functionality to make something focus when the validation fails. I cannot use onclick as the page will not let me submit the form due to the validation, so I cannot run an onclick

Answer (score 1):

```
 var controls = $("#divid").find('.class'); 
 $.each(controls, function (index, item) { 
       $("#form1").validate().element($(this)); 
       if ($(this).valid) { 
         //skip it maybe 
       } else { 
            //do something, even an ajax call if need be 
       }
```

Comment: thats the way using normal validation, not unobtrusive. By default MVC fires the validation

Comment: That is checking the required attribute which is the unobtrusive way. this is the way I've found to catch any individual error and do something about it, say, focus on that field, $(this).focus(), or display a message or whatever.